# How to find the index of torch tensor where the maximum value is occurring?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

Suppose I have the following tensor called `a`:

```
>>> a = torch.randn(10)
Out[32]: 
tensor([-0.6936,  1.2862,  0.2096, -0.8629, -3.0095, -0.7957, -0.9336,  0.0622,
        -0.3510, -0.1518])
```

How can I find the index of this tensor where the maximum value is occurring (which in this case the position 1 (=1.2862))?

Thank you,

Comment: `torch.argmax(a)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the max index for each row in a tensor object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54681798/how-to-find-the-max-index-for-each-row-in-a-tensor-object)